# OpenStack single installer increase glance storage space

Tags: openstack

I just installed openstack on 14.04 with that

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:cloud-installer/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openstack
sudo openstack-install --openstack-release icehouse
```

and I selected the option to have everything on a single machine. Now the installer says that glance has 20GB of storage. How can I increase that number?

Comment: Also by default the installer uses Juno release, is there a particular reason why you need Icehouse?

Comment: The customer uses that.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the sizes of the VM's via a configuration file containing your services placements and their constraints.

```
install_type: Single
placements:
  controller:
    assignments:
      LXC:
      - nova-cloud-controller
      - glance
      - glance-simplestreams-sync
      - openstack-dashboard
      - juju-gui
      - keystone
      - mysql
      - neutron-api
      - neutron-openvswitch
      - rabbitmq-server
      - swift-proxy
    constraints:
      cpu-cores: 2
      mem: 6144
      root-disk: 20480
  nova-compute-machine-0:
    assignments:
      BareMetal:
      - nova-compute
    constraints:
      mem: 4096
      root-disk: 40960
  quantum-gateway-machine-0:
    assignments:
      BareMetal:
      - quantum-gateway
    constraints:
      mem: 2048
      root-disk: 20480
  swift-storage-machine-0:
    assignments:
      BareMetal:
      - swift-storage
    constraints: &id001 {}
  swift-storage-machine-1:
    assignments:
      BareMetal:
      - swift-storage
    constraints: *id001
  swift-storage-machine-2:
    assignments:
      BareMetal:
      - swift-storage
    constraints: *id001
```

For a walkthrough with examples have a look at http://astokes.org/openstack-installer-customizing-the-single-install-constraints/

Comment: Any ways to do it without redeploying? I was thinking maybe with some lxc command.

Comment: Not that I know of. You could destroy the service directly and re-add a new machine with those constraints if you didn't want to do another full deploy.